# junit 4.8.1 and spring 3.0.5 example

Tags: java

can any one help me in writing junit test case for spring MVC controler for the following versions
spring 3.0.5
junit 4.8.1
spring test :3.0.5 release

i found some exmaples with other versions like spring 3.2.5
junit 4.11
spring test 3.2.5

Comment: When you say "Can you help me writing JUnit test case for Spring MVC Controller" - what do you actually mean? You don't know how to test an MVC?

Comment: Spring MVC has introduced the testing framework in 3.2.x. If you can't upgrade, get the framework separately from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Just create a test class annotate its methods with @Test, call controller methods and run. It is recommended to place test class in the same package as tested class just in different directory. For instance, **src** tree and **test** tree.